# Initialize variable with annotations

Tags: java, annotations

i want to make my own annotation to initialize a class field. I need something like this:

```
public class MyAnnotationClass{
    Map<String,String> myMap;

    public String getValue(String key) {
        return myMap.get(key);
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String[] keys default {};
    String[] vlaues default {};
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @MyAnnotation(keys={"a","b"},values={"A","B"})
    MyAnnotationClass myAnnotationClass;

    public MyAnnotationClass getMyAnnotationClass() {
        return this.myAnnotationClass;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to initialize the variable, or what i'm missing.

Thanks you!

EDIT:
I'ts a little more complex than that. I need to initialize it that way.

Also i'm using play framework

Comment: Why don't you just initialize it without annotations? What do annotations really add here?

Comment: You'll need something to process the annotation. This (with the sample you've given) seems much more complex than just doing it yourself.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Initialize which variable? You have several uninitialized variables. What has initialization have anything to do with annotations?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information to be able to help you better.

Generally speaking, annotations can be processed during compilation from source code or compiled classes, or you can process them at runtime. See [RetentionPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)

If you need to initialize them during compile process then you need to do either:

1. Parse the source code, rewrite your variable, then compile the class.
2. In case you want to modify the .class file, then you need a library like javaassist or ASM from ObjectWeb.

In both cases, you will need to write an annotation processor.

At runtime you can initialize them using reflection. This is probably the simplest way.